# Get object with list from firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class for users

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("username")
private String userName;
@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
@SerializedName("bags")
private List<Bag> bags;
.
.
.
```

And I have this data in my firebase DB

[image]

Before I added the "bags" items, the object was created fine, I'm using this method for retrieving the user by the uid:

```
public void retrieveUserByUid(String uid, FirebaseRetrieveUserListener listener){
    Query userQuery = dbReference.child(FirebaseChild.users.name()).child(uid);

    final FirebaseRetrieveUserListener dataListener = listener;

    userQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            dataListener.retrieveUserByUid(user);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

As I said, this worked without the "bags" item, when I put it, the error I'm getting is this.

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
```

This happens when I try to do this

```
 User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
```

I've searched a lot about how to retrieve a list, but all I find is retrieving a single list object, not a "mixed" object with "single data" and a list.

Comment: I think manual deserialization is better way in that case. But you may try to use type `HashMap<String, Bag>` for bags property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
@SerializedName("bags")
private Map<String,Bag> bags;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you error says, while deserializing it was expected a `HashMap` and not a `List`. Because Firebase is a NoSQL database, everything in Firbease is structured as pairs of key and value. So every node in Firebase is a `Map`. In order to solve this, change the `bags` from List to `HashMap` and your problem will be solved.

You can also try this:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<List<YourClass>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Message>>() {};
List<YourClass> messages = snapshot.getValue(t);
```

Comment: I tried, but now the error is this: `Class java.util.HashMap has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead`